# What is the T-SQL To grant read and write access to tables in a database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the exact SQL to assign `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles to a user in SQL Server?

The user name is `MYUSER` and the database is `MYDB`.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, 2014:

```
USE mydb
GO

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER MYUSER
GO
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER MYUSER
GO
```

In SQL Server 2008:

```
use mydb
go

exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, MYUSER 
go
exec sp_addrolemember db_datawriter, MYUSER 
go
```

To also assign the ability to execute all Stored Procedures for a Database:

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO MYUSER;
```

To assign the ability to execute specific stored procedures:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_mystoredprocedure TO MYUSER;
```

Answer (score 12):

From SQLServer 2012 more elegant [alter role](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx):

```
use mydb
go

ALTER ROLE db_datareader
  ADD MEMBER MYUSER 
go
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter
  ADD MEMBER MYUSER 
go
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to Create a New role, then grant execute, select ... etc permissions to this role and finally assign users to this role.

Create role

```
CREATE ROLE [db_SomeExecutor] 
GO
```

Grant Permission to this role

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_SomeExecutor
GRANT INSERT  TO db_SomeExecutor
```

to Add users database>security> > roles > databaseroles>Properties > Add ( bottom right ) you can search AD users and add then

OR

```
   EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_SomeExecutor', 'domainName\UserName'
```

Please refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998634/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-grant-privileges-to-a-username)