# SQL Server 2008: how do I grant privileges to a username?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I need to be able to establish an ODBC connection through SQL Server authentication.

In SSMS how do I grant permission for a user to be able to have ALL RIGHTS on a specific database?

is there a way to do this graphically with SSMS?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If you want to give your user all read permissions, you could use:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'your-user-name'
```

That adds the default `db_datareader` role (read permission on all tables) to that user.

There's also a `db_datawriter` role - which gives your user all WRITE permissions (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) on all tables:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'your-user-name'
```

If you need to be more granular, you can use the `GRANT` command:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON dbo.YourTable TO YourUserName
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON dbo.YourTable2 TO YourUserName
GRANT SELECT, DELETE ON dbo.YourTable3 TO YourUserName
```

and so forth - you can granularly give SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE permission on specific tables.

This is all very well documented in the [MSDN Books Online for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx).

And yes, you can also do it graphically - in SSMS, go to your database, then `Security > Users`, right-click on that user you want to give permissions to, then `Properties` adn at the bottom you see "Database role memberships" where you can add the user to db roles.

[image]

Comment: somehow I don't have Users node in Security tree in SSMS, only Logins & Credentials - apart from this, in order for sp_addrolemember to work, the user has to be mapped to the database in question, otherwise "user ... does not exist in the database" error is given (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232559/mssql-giving-loginsusers-db-owner-access-to-database - see comments to the accepted answer) - i could to user-db mapping through Properties of the user's Login object

Comment: @marc_s, How to grant permission related to a particular table using SSMS?

Comment: @Chathuranga: read the [excellent, freely available docs!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)

Answer (score 68):

If you really want them to have ALL rights:

```
use YourDatabase
go
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'UserName'
go
```

Answer (score 21):

Like the following. It will make the user database owner.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'USerNAme'
```