# Programmatically set a DB user to be db_owner

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I assign the `db_owner` role to a user that I have created?

I am able to create a login and add them to the database. I don't know how to change their permission to `db_owner` using a SQL query.

I have a feeling I am maybe missing something with my query where I add the user to the database?

Here is the query to add the user to the database

```
CREATE USER [Driver-SOC-ChrisTest] FOR LOGIN [Driver-SOC-ChrisTest] 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

Comment: See this answer for SQL Server 2008 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998634/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-grant-privileges-to-a-username

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To give the user DBO permissions:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'[Driver-SOC-ChrisTest]'
```

To make the user owner of the database (not advised):

```
EXEC sp_changedbowner N'[Driver-SOC-ChrisTest]'
```

Answer (score 24):

I quite often go into the GUI, make the changes I need and then rather than saving by pressing OK, I press the Script button at the top of the dialog and send it to a new window.

[image]

This would give you the code the previous poster provided.

Comment: This is genius! How did I not know this? So useful.

Comment: Unfortunately cannot vote up more than once :P Too useful.

Comment: Very good tip. Not only does it solve the problem but now I will know how to execute many queries in SQL.