# SQL Server giving logins(users) db_owner access to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We have a test database and some test logins that we would like to give db_owner access to through a script. Usually we would have to go into logins and right click on the username and go to user mapping and select the database to associate it with and give it owner access and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to do two things, both running in the context of the target database (i.e., execute `USE (database)` first):

1. Add that user as a login to the database: `CREATE USER [LoginName] FOR LOGIN [LoginName]`
2. Add that user to the role: `EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'LoginName'`

In general, if you have SQL Server Management Studio 2005 or higher, you can go into the UI for an operation, fill out the dialog box (in this case, assigning the user to the database & adding roles), and then click the "Script" button at the top. Instead of executing the command, it will write a script for the action to a new query window.

Comment: What if the user already exist just needs to be mapped to the database first and then run the sp_addrolemember SP. Can this be done?

Comment: The mapping to the database *is* the first query.  It assumes a login (username/password) has already been created on the server.  You can check if they have already been mapped by looking at `sys.database_principals` in the target database.

Comment: It works, but according to the MSDN docs, this sproc is now deprecated. I tried doing it with ALTER ROLE as the alternative the docs suggested, but as pointed out it doesn't work with built-in roles. Any idea how this can be done without this sproc?

Answer (score 45):

I'd like to propose another solution which may help someone...

```
-- create the user on the master database
USE [master] 
GO
CREATE LOGIN [MyUserName] WITH PASSWORD=N'MyPassword'
CREATE USER [MyUserName] FOR LOGIN [MyUserName]
GO

-- create the user on the target database for the login
USE [MyDatabaseName]
GO
CREATE USER [MyUserName] FOR LOGIN [MyUserName]
GO

-- add the user to the desired role
USE [MyDatabaseName]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [MyUserName]
GO
```

Comment: Perfect! Spent an hour looking for an all-in-one solution and this was it. Cheers!

Comment: Best of Best!!!

Answer (score 17):

Here is how to use `ALTER ROLE` with an existing server login named `MyLogin`.

```
USE MyDatabase
CREATE USER MyLogin FOR LOGIN MyLogin
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER MyLogin
GO
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql

Answer (score 16):

Use [sp_addrolemember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx)

> EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'MyUser'

Comment: I tried that one and it says Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 75
User or role 'QA-Tester1' does not exist in this database.

Comment: You have to add the role first then you can add the user to that role

Comment: Apparently and according to the documentation, ALTER ROLE is preferred (the original answer was posted in 2011, this comment is from 2024. Source:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2):

Add login, add user with default schema 'dbo', add user to role, and also be able to run it again with no errors, and on Azure or local SQL Servers:

```
--note login and user have same name
-- change the names of: DBNAME, PASSWORDHERE and LOGINNAMEHERE

--1 create login
use master
GO
IF not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = N'LOGINNAMEHERE')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [LOGINNAMEHERE] WITH PASSWORD=N'PASSWORDHERE'
END

--2 on DB create User
use DBNAME
GO

if (Not Exists(select * from sys.sysusers where name = 'LOGINNAMEHERE'))
BEGIN;
    CREATE USER [LOGINNAMEHERE] FOR LOGIN [LOGINNAMEHERE] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
END;
GO

--3 insert role membership
IF ((select ISNULL(is_rolemember('db_owner', 'LOGINNAMEHERE'),0)) <> 1)
BEGIN;
    --EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'LOGINNAMEHERE'
    ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [LOGINNAMEHERE];
END;
IF ((select ISNULL(is_rolemember('db_owner', 'LOGINNAMEHERE'),0)) <> 1)
BEGIN;
    PRINT 'user not added to role try sp_addrolemember';
END;
```