# How to fix "The current user is not an owner of the selected database." when exporting data from one SQL Server 2016 to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am facing an error as below when I try to Export one database to another database in SQL Server 2016:

> The current user is not an owner of the selected database.

[image: screenshot]

The user in source SQL Server is  'sa' and the destination user is 'Christiano'.
So which user the **"The current user is not an owner of the selected database."** indicates and how to give a proper permission or ownership?
The 'sa' user also is the Owner of the database in source SQL Server.

Comment: You need to add Christiano to the Owner role.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232559/sql-server-giving-loginsusers-db-owner-access-to-database

Comment: Thank you @devlincarnate. I created Christiano in source and added Christiano as the owner of the Database but still same warning which leads to the error. I noticed while the Christiano is one of the owners now, it only shows 'sa' as the Owner of the database when I click on Properties, Should I restart the SQL Server?

Comment: The error is telling you that this problem is in the destination database, not the source.  The "current user" is whatever you are logged into in the source.  That user must be in the destination in the owner role.  So if you are Christiano in the source, Christiano needs to be in the destination, as owner

Comment: I also made sure that Christiano is the owner with **EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'Christiano'** within the database

Comment: Oh I see. I will look into it now. Thank you @devlincarnate

Comment: I checked the destination as well, Christiano is the owner of that database

Comment: This is fixed. I grant same permission as 'SA' permission to Christiano and now it is exporting fine. I will change the permission again when I am done with exporting. Thank you @devlincarnate