# Permissions require to GRANT EXECUTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

I am creating a group for users who will need to be able to create and delete procs but also grant execute permissions to other users.

```
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO [xxx\xxx]
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO [xxx\xxx]
```

However what permissions to I need to grant the group such that they can grant execute permissions to an object?

Thanks

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998634/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-grant-privileges-to-a-username) it's a thread about granting various permissions. You may just have to grant these people ALL privileges

Comment: @tkendrick20 the accepted answer there shows how to grant certain permissions (but not execute, or the ability to grant execute); the other answers there all seem to imply that the "solution" is to put the user in the db_owner role.

Comment: Would that not be a solution?

Comment: @tkendrick20 it's "a" solution, sure. But it might be giving more power than intended and needed. Why not just make them sysadmin? That would work too.

Comment: Cool, that makes 2 solutions

Comment: @tkendrick20 It's a solution in the same way that removing all locks from your home is a "solution" to giving a guest access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx), this is supposed to work:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [xxx\xxx] WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

However in my minimal testing it required:

```
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [xxx\xxx];
```

I strongly recommend you don't follow the advice in the comments, which suggest it might be a good idea to "grant ALL permissions" or use `db_owner` or `sysadmin`. Granting someone more permissions than they need is just a lazy way to ensure you will get fired later. I recommend anyone advocating this blind giving of keys to the castle to review [the principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).