# Grant/revoke execute permission to procedure from package

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsql-package

I've couple of stored procedures(Let's say `PROC_1` and `PROC_2`) inside one package(i.e. `PROC_PKG`) which is under one of schema/user (i.e. `A`).

I need to grant execute permission to another user(i.e. `B`).

So I've already tried with following commands:

`grant execute on PROC_1 TO B;`

`grant execute on A.PROC_1 TO B;`

`grant execute on PROC_PKG.PROC_1 TO B;`

`grant execute on A.PROC_PKG.PROC_1 TO B;`

*I've already looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17951744/3510195) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4305531/3510195) answers but they didn't helped me.*

---

**PS:** I want to allow user `B` to access only `PROC_1` that means user `B` should not be able to access `PROC_2` from the same package.

Comment: package is a unit you can grant privileges on package and not on each procedure in a package . for that case you should create stored procedure

Comment: Can't be done. You could possibly let PROC_2 decide whether the calling user is allowed and throw an exception if not; but not through direct privilege grants. One possibility might be through roles and checking if the user has a specific role enabled, but that seems a long way from where you are now.

Comment: Got it and added the same in the answer for further reference. thanks a lot guys for hint.

Answer (score 3):

We can not grant execute privilege to individual stored procedure or function from package. **So either we can grant execute privilege to every stored procedure/functions from package or none of them from package.**

In-fact this is one of the advantage of Package:
[You can grant roles on the package, instead of granting roles on each object in the package.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/packages.htm#LNPLS00904)

Following query will grant execute privilege to user `B` from user `A`*(That will allow user `B` to execute every stored procedure/functions from that package).*

`GRANT EXECUTE ON PROC_PKG TO B;`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Alex Poole one workaround with ROLES would be like this:

```
CREATE ROLE EXECUTE_PROC_1 NOT IDENTIFIED;

GRANT EXECUTE_PROC_1 TO B;
ALTER USER B DEFAULT ROLE ALL;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE AS
   PROCEDURE PROC_1 IS
   BEGIN
       IF NOT DBMS_SESSION.IS_ROLE_ENABLED('EXECUTE_PROC_1') THEN
           RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Not permitted');
       END IF;
       -- Do your stuff
   END;
END MY_PACKAGE;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate "wrapper" procedure which executes only A.PROC_PKG.PROC_1 and then grant execute on that separately to B.