# ssis 2012 packages deployment error

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

when  I deployed ssis packages that time I faced one error.please tell me how to resolve that issue in ssis package deployment time.it is seems permission related what i do exactely to give permission or any other ways.please tell me how resolve it.

error:
the select permission was denied on the object 'projects',database 'ssidb',shema'catalog'

Comment: Did you tried to [**search**](https://www.google.hu/webhp?q=the+select+permission+was+denied+on+the+object+%27projects%27,database+%27ssisdb%27,schema+catalog%27&spell=1) that error message? BTW check this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2012/03/20/ssis-catalog-access-control-tips.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would start by finding out the account that the SSIS package is running under.  Are you executing it via a SQL job?  You can check what account is executing it from there if that is the case.

The error stated is pretty obvious - the user that is currently executing the SSIS package does not have select permissions on the appropriate objects.

You can check out some information on configuring SQL user account at: [SQL Server 2008: how do I grant privileges to a username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998634/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-grant-privileges-to-a-username)