# Can't add user to db_datareader via script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following script:

```
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [DomainGroup123]
```

when I run this against SQL Server 2008 R2 I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ADD'.

I have looked online, and found [examples](http://sql-articles.com/articles/general/contained-database-sql-server-2012/) that use this exact statement (but with a different user.)

I have double checked that the login exists and is a valid user on the database I am using.  Also I have SA permissions on the server.

What am I mssing?

Comment: Although you've already found a solution, please note that the documentation for `ALTER ROLE` shows that the syntax you tried is only valid in [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775(v=sql.110).aspx), not [SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @Pondlife is right.  Note: You should use "ALTER ROLE" for any future development in SS2012 on up.  Proof: Microsoft's "Important" Note here on [sp_addrolemember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) explicitly says to use "ALTER ROLE" instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use sp_addrolemember.

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember db_datareader, 'UserName'
```

Answer (score 9):

Found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/456365/16241

That showed me that I can run it like this:

```
exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [DomainGroup123]
```

I did that and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed that depending on the version of the server, I need to go one of the following.

```
alter role RoleName add member UserName
```

or

```
execute sp_addrolemember RoleName, UserName
```

I'm thinking of changing my approach from trial-and-error to some kind of conditional but (a) this operation is performed quite seldom in my case and (b) I'm a bit lazy nowadays.